# USB input devices not working under Xorg for a single user

Tags: xorg, usb-device

I have a strange occasional buggy behaviour that I'm trying to trace and solve on my laptop.

Occasionally, wired USB input devices (mouse and keyboard) stop working under an Xorg XFCE session. There is no consistency whether they appear to be powered or not (NumLock and CapsLock LEDs can or cannot light up, e.g), but they do not move the pointer or input text, whereas built-in keyboard and touchpad do. They are listed in `lsusb` though, and if I use (built-in keyboard's) <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> to go to tty1, or if I open another graphical user session in tty8, mouse and keyboard work as expected.

I'm using a laptop with a USB-C docking station (I first thought this interfered, but this is the case whether connected via the docking station's USB hub or not, and persists when unplugging it) and I'm running Debian Bullseye with XFCE under lightdm. When bug occurs, attempting to `service restart lightdm` restored only one of the devices. Starting `gdm3` 3.38.2.1-1 in another tty was simultaneously having the problem with both input devices. Dowgrading `lightdm` to stable debian version 1.26.0-4 did not change anything. Restarting system did (for this instance) restore both devices with lightm/bullseye.

**EDIT:** After a long time, I've had that issue again. Both external devices where plugged into USB-C docking station and seemed not to be powered, `xinput` couldn't see them:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0815:00 044E:120A Mouse               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0815:00 044E:120A Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL0815:00 044E:120A UNKNOWN             id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Then 3 minutes later I unplugged one of them (mouse) from docking station and plugged it directy to the laptop, both were suddenly activated, see `dmesg`:

```
[1184725.182186] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 37, error -71
[1184725.182343] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[1184725.266717] usb 2-1.2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[1184725.287315] usb 2-1.2: Dell TB16 Dock, disable RX aggregation
[1184725.290078] r8152 2-1.2:1.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8153a-3.fw (-2)
[1184725.290083] r8152 2-1.2:1.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8153a-3.fw failed with error -2
[1184725.290087] r8152 2-1.2:1.0: unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8153a-3.fw (-2)
[1184725.290227] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Using pass-thru MAC addr e4:b9:7a:7f:5a:b6
[1184725.320675] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 eth0: v1.11.11
[1184725.626338] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[1184725.626530] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[1184725.834454] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[1184726.042190] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 38, error -71
[1184726.170294] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
[1184726.170471] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[1184726.378522] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[1184726.586408] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 39, error -71
[1184726.586484] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[1184726.620595] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 enxe4b97a7f5ab6: renamed from eth0
[1184728.395840] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enxe4b97a7f5ab6: link becomes ready
[1184728.396250] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 enxe4b97a7f5ab6: carrier on
[1184988.175205] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 enxe4b97a7f5ab6: carrier off
[1184991.337451] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 40 using xhci_hcd
[1184991.486320] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2807, bcdDevice= 2.04
[1184991.486326] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[1184991.486329] usb 1-1: Product: USB2807 Hub
[1184991.486332] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Microchip
[1184991.487314] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[1184991.487380] hub 1-1:1.0: 7 ports detected
[1184991.531285] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 enxe4b97a7f5ab6: carrier on
[1184991.617517] usb 1-9: new low-speed USB device number 41 using xhci_hcd
[1184991.771119] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2107, bcdDevice= 1.04
[1184991.771126] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[1184991.771130] usb 1-9: Product: Dell USB Entry Keyboard
[1184991.771133] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: DELL
[1184991.775512] input: DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0161/input/input325
[1184991.834188] hid-generic 0003:413C:2107.0161: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9/input0
[1184991.845377] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[1184992.370896] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 enxe4b97a7f5ab6: carrier off
[1184992.405048] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=4014, bcdDevice= 0.05
[1184992.405052] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[1184992.405055] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB Audio
[1184992.405058] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Generic
[1184992.405060] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[1184993.353588] usb 1-1.7: new low-speed USB device number 43 using xhci_hcd
[1184993.458257] usb 1-1.7: New USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=4d17, bcdDevice= 2.00
[1184993.458264] usb 1-1.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[1184993.458268] usb 1-1.7: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[1184993.464432] input: USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.7/1-1.7:1.0/0003:0461:4D17.0162/input/input326
[1184993.465105] hid-generic 0003:0461:4D17.0162: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.7/input0
[1184996.010910] r8152 2-1.2:1.0 enxe4b97a7f5ab6: carrier on
```

and `xinput` added them to its list of devices:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0815:00 044E:120A Mouse               id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0815:00 044E:120A Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL0815:00 044E:120A UNKNOWN             id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=19   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It seems to me the problem corresponds to the errors

```
[1184725.626338] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[1184725.626530] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[1184725.834454] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[1184726.042190] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 38, error -71
```

in this instance, which seems to contradict the fact that in previous ones, devices were listed by `lsusb`... which I hadn't tried in this instance.

Comment: Just to clarify - which Debian release? Do I understand correctly that you see this behavior also when you connect the mouse and kbd directly to the system? Are they wired or connected with a USB dongle? Please don't answer in a comment, update your question instead.

Comment: @Peregrino69: thks for comment, I've added details.

Comment: Experiment with command `xinput`. Does it list the devices? Can you `list-props` on them? Does `--reattach` do something? Or `--enable`?

Comment: Thanks @meuh - I'll test that when bug reappears, which it usually doesn't fail to do about once in a week with my usual usage.